# what is difference between Mapr nfs and HDFS nfs?

Tags: hdfs, nfs, mapr

What is difference between Mapr nfs and HDFS nfs.

My understanding is as following-

- Mapr nfs is read/write but HDFS nfs is read only.
- Mapr nfs don't use any intermediate file system but HDFS nfs stores
  file in an   intermediate file system(ex- xfs).

I am unclear about second point that, why intermediate file system in case of HDFS nfs is required?

Please put your thoughts on this.